# When will following method return 2

Tags: java, string, split

I am curious to find out under what circumstances following method will return 2 instead of 1.

```
   private int splitString(String strToSplit) {
        int num = strToSplit.split("[\\W_]+").length;
        if (num == 0) {
            System.out.println("Value is :: " + 2);
            return 2;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Note that "throw" is usually used with exceptions. Your method doesn't throw 2, it _returns_ 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` discards trailing empty strings, so if `strToSplit` contains only delimiters

```
strToSplit == "____"
```

then `split` will return an empty array and your method will, accordingly, return `2`.

Note that if `split` finds no matches of the pattern in the string then the entire string is returned, so if

```
strToSplit == ""
```

i.e. an empty string, then `split` will return a one element array, and your method will return `1` instead of `2`.